# Attempted import error: 'useControlled' is not exported from '@material-ui/core/utils'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
./node_modules/@material-ui/lab/esm/useAutocomplete/useAutocomplete.js 
Attempted import error: 'useControlled' is not exported from '@material-ui/core/utils'.
```

Facing this issue , how to fix ?

corresponding versions

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.8.3",
"@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.44",
```

[Link for the component which i am using](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#multiple-values)

Comment: Hi, were you able to resolve this?

Comment: hi @ChetanKB, first answer resolved my problem and i have marked that answer too

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You’re using the latest version of the lab, but an older version of core. Switch to 4.9.4 for core and it should be fine.

Comment: the hero we needed

Answer (score 2):

## missing some path

Your import statement should be

`import useControlled from '@material-ui/core/utils/useControlled'`

There is no index file in utils.

Comment: there is no use of useControlled in my js file, i am trying to use AutoColpmete from mui/Lab and got this error

Answer (score 2):

Changing the the version of the packages didn't work for me. The issue was with the refrencing path in the import statement.

replace

```
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab";
```

with

```
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
```

Answer (score 0):

try updating @material-ui/core by running

npm update

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
import { useControlled } from '@mui/material';
```